# Is there a word for people who worship/glorify something just because it's old?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not talking about religion.  Imagine certain Ancient Egyptian writing or old Chinese poem or phrase by Shakespeare, comment on life being very short or we being puppets in the theater of life.  Some people seem to think that just because this is very old, than mere repetition of the phrase has a certain authority or importance or power above and beyond what some brilliant philosopher at present might say.  There is a kind of glorification of it beyond the thought expressed, mere reason that it's old or very old.  So these people constantly quote this or that ancient writing as if it's proof of veracity of certain view.  Is there a word for these people or this act?

Any idea?

Edit: thank you, it's similar to the other question, consider this solved.

Answer (score 1):

The item that is being honored could be said to be ***venerable***:

> : old and respected
> : valued and respected because of old age, long use, etc.
>   
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/venerable)</sub>

To honor such an item is to ***venerate*** it. In the synonym discussion of *venerate*, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/venerate) offers:

> VENERATE implies a holding as holy or sacrosanct because of character, association, or age.

So, a person that honors such an item could be called a ***[venerator](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/venerator)***.

Comment: This probably won't do. *Venerator* doesn't carry the connotation of age that *venerable* does.  It's almost always followed by a prepositional phrase with *of* giving the the thing admired, which thing need not be of long standing.

Comment: @deadrat: The synonym discussion for [*venerate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/venerate) in M-W did offer a connotation of age, so I think *venerator* could offer a similar connotation. However I agree it is indeed not strongly linked like *venerable*.